# Kohana Framework running on multiple servers

Tags: php, frameworks, kohana

I want to know if possible, separate the Kohana's controllers in multiple servers, and spread the load between this servers

Comment: Explain your issue better.

Comment: Hello, how are you? I want to do is the following, for example the registration controller to work on a server, the message handler on another server, to spread the load across multiple servers, it would be possible?

Thanks

Comment: i dont think its possible with kohana, but there are other better ways to handle application load, one is to have db replication and use master slave database structure, secondly you could have multiple server instances to handle the load using load balancers, using which your main server will get the traffic and route to appropriate(free) server. your system admin could better guide to make an architecture.